# None Type error in Python when running streamlit

Tags: python, function, streamlit

Hi I am trying create an App in python that will allow users to choose which classification model they want to implement on one of three open source data in SK-Learn library The code is the following:

```
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier


st.title("Streamlit example")

st.write("""
# Explore different classifier
which one is the best?
""")

dataset_name = st.sidebar.selectbox("Select Dataset", ("Iris","Breast Cancer","Wine Dataset") )

classifier_name  = st.sidebar.selectbox("Select Classifier", ("KNN","SVM","Random Forest") )

def get_dataset(dataset_name):
    if dataset_name == "Iris":
        data = datasets.load_iris()

    elif dataset_name == "Breast Cancer":
        data = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
    else:
        data = datasets.load_wine()

    X = data.data
    y = data.target
    return X, y

X, y  = get_dataset(dataset_name)

st.write("Shape of datset", X.shape)
st.write("Number of classes", len(np.unique(y)))

def add_parameter_ui(clf_name):
    params = dict()
    if clf_name =="KNN":
        K = st.sidebar.slider("K",1,15)
        params["K"] = K
    elif clf_name =="SVM":
        C = st.sidebar.slider("C", 0.01,10.0)
        params["C"] = C
    else:
        max_depth = st.sidebar.slider("max_depth", 2,15)
        n_estimators = st.sidebar.slider("n_estimators",1,100)
        params["max_depth"]= max_depth
        params["n_estimators"] = n_estimators
        return params


params = add_parameter_ui(classifier_name)

def get_classifier(clf_name,params):
    
    if clf_name == "KNN":
        clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=params['K'])
       
    elif clf_name == "SVM":
        clf = SVC(C= params['C'])
 
    else:
        clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=params["n_estimators"],max_depth=params["max_depth"],random_state=1234)


    return clf

clf = get_classifier(classifier_name,params)
```

The error is:

```
   clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=params['K'])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I know the error is supposed to be self-explanatory but I tried to state `clf = None` but still get the same error and i'm asking someone to put me in the right direction.

Comment: Does your data contain any `null` or `None` values?

Comment: Could you add the complete `TracebackError`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your add_parameter_ui function. you are not returning a value in the case of clf_name is KNN or SVM and this causes params in the main code to be None so calling params['K'] is not because 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

Here is the fixed code:

```
def add_parameter_ui(clf_name):
    params = dict()
    if clf_name =="KNN":
        K = st.sidebar.slider("K",1,15)
        params["K"] = K
        return params
    elif clf_name =="SVM":
        C = st.sidebar.slider("C", 0.01,10.0)
        params["C"] = C
        return params
    # If Random Forest
    max_depth = st.sidebar.slider("max_depth", 2,15)
    n_estimators = st.sidebar.slider("n_estimators",1,100)
    params["max_depth"]= max_depth
    params["n_estimators"] = n_estimators
    return params
```